# StarCraft Brood War online?

Tags: battle.net, starcraft

Is it still possible to play Star Craft Brood War online on Battle.net?

What do I need aside from the original game?

Do I need to pay a subscription fee on Battle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to pay a fee.

Battle.Net is currently still free.  You need to sign up for an account, apply all the patches (it is done automatically when you try to access battle.net), and that's it.

Comment: Are all European servers still working?

Comment: @Cyberpower There is an EU "Gateway" which I guess is sort of like a server, but the game itself is played P2P. Battle.net is just a way for you to match up with others.